# How do I select all(*) in a row where a column eg. PHONE ends with certain intergers?

Tags: mysql, substring

Example:

```
<?php
$Number = 123456789

$NewNumber = substr($dynamicstring, -4);

//How do I select the row in a mysql database where for example the column "PHONE" ends with $NewNumber?
?>
```

I am trying to return a row in my mysql database where the column "PHONE" ends with a dynamic string.

Comment: `WHERE PHONE LIKE %$NewNumber`

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: There is another syntax error, like using `substr`

      $Number = '1236549431';
      $dynamicstring  = substr($Number, -4);
      $strqry = "SELECT * FROM contact Where PHONE like " . "'%" . $dynamicstring . "'";